# Use L'Hopital's Rule to Prove

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $$f: \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$$ be differentiable, let a in $\mathbb R$. Suppose that $f''(a)$ exists. Prove that $$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h)}{h^2}=f''(a) $$

Suppose further that $f''(x)$ exists for all $x$, and that $f'''(0)$ exists. Prove that $$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{4(f(h)-f(-h)-2(f(h/2)-f(-h/2)))}{h^3}=f'''(0)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The earlier accepted answer here (by Priyatham) had a subtle flaw (namely repeated use of L'Hospital's Rule without checking conditions of its applicability) but it has been fixed now after my comments.

I am sure this question is solved elsewhere on MSE, but I am not able to find link. Here is the right approach to this question.

1) We will use L'Hospital's rule as follows: $$\begin{aligned}L &= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(a + h) - 2f(a) + f(a - h)}{h^{2}}\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f'(a + h) - f'(a - h)}{2h}\text{ (by L'Hospital's Rule)}\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f'(a + h) - f'(a) + f'(a) - f'(a - h)}{2h}\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f'(a + h) - f'(a)}{2h} + \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f'(a - h) - f'(a)}{-2h}\\
&= \frac{f''(a)}{2} + \frac{f''(a)}{2} = f''(a)\end{aligned}$$ 2) Again we use L'Hospital's rule: $$\begin{aligned}L &= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{4\left\{f(h) - f(-h) - 2\{f(h/2) - f(-h/2)\}\right\}}{h^{3}}\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{4\left\{f'(h) + f'(-h) - \{f'(h/2) + f'(-h/2)\}\right\}}{3h^{2}}\text{ (by L'Hospital's Rule)}\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{4\left\{f''(h) - f''(-h) - (1/2)\{f''(h/2) - f''(-h/2)\}\right\}}{6h}\text{ (by L'Hospital's Rule)}\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{4\left\{f''(h) - f''(0) + f''(0) - f''(-h) - (1/2)\{f''(h/2) - f''(0) + f''(0) - f''(-h/2)\}\right\}}{6h}\\
&= \frac{2}{3}\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f''(h) - f''(0)}{h} + \frac{2}{3}\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f''(-h) - f''(0)}{-h} - \frac{1}{6}\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f''(h/2) - f''(0)}{h/2}\\
&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,-\frac{1}{6}\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f''(-h/2) - f''(0)}{-h/2}\\
&= \frac{2}{3}f'''(0) + \frac{2}{3}f'''(0) - \frac{1}{6}f'''(0) - \frac{1}{6}f'''(0)\\
&= f'''(0)\end{aligned}$$

Comment: That's great. I was worrying about whether L'Hopital rule is applicable at every stage. Thank you very much.

Comment: @SeanWillington: Just to clarify, L'Hospital's rule is applicable only when both the numerator and denominator are differentiable in a certain neighborhood of the point under consideration (but not necessarily differentiable at that point).

Answer (score 3):

**Question 1**
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h)}{h^2} \\
$$
when $h = 0$ is substituted numerator and denominator reduce to $0$. So, applying L'Hopital's rule (differentiate wrt $h$)
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f'(a+h)-f'(a-h)}{2h} \\
\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f'(a+h)-f'(a)-f'(a-h)+f'(a)}{2h} \\
\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f'(a+h)-f'(a)}{2h}+\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f'(a)-f'(a-h)}{2h} \\
= \frac{2f''(a)}{2} = f''(a)\\
$$
**Question 2**
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{4(f(h)-f(-h)-2(f(h/2)-f(-h/2)))}{h^3}
$$
when h=0 is substituted numerator and denominator reduce to 0. So, applying L'Hopital's rule (differentiate wrt h)
$$
\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{4(f'(h)+f'(-h)-f'(h/2)-f'(-h/2))}{3h^2} \\
= \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{4(f''(h)-f''(0)+f''(0)-f''(-h)+\frac{1}{2}f''(0)-\frac{1}{2}f''(h/2)-\frac{1}{2}f''(0)+\frac{1}{2}f''(-h/2))}{6h} \\
= \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{4(f''(h)-f''(0)+f''(0)-f''(-h)+\frac{1}{2}f''(0)-\frac{1}{2}f''(h/2)-\frac{1}{2}f''(0)+\frac{1}{2}f''(-h/2))}{6h} \\
= \frac{2}{3}\left(\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f''(h)-f''(0)}{h}+\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f''(0)-f''(-h)}{h}\right)+\frac{1}{3}\left(\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f''(0)-f''(h/2)}{h}+\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f''(-h/2)-f''(0)}{h}\right) \\
= \frac{4f'''(0)}{3}-\frac{f'''(0)}{3} = f'''(0)
$$
PS: Thanks to @Paramanand Singh for pointing out that f was not twice and thrice differentiable in first and second questions respectively.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just a quick question, the assumption is f''(a) exists.Can we deduce that f' is differentiable and continuous, so L'Hopital is applicable?

Comment: The first derivative must be differentiable (and continuous) for us to talk about the second derivative, right?

Comment: @Priyatham: Your solution has a subtle flaw. In the first limit you can't apply L'Hospital Rule twice. And in the second limit you can't apply L'Hospital thrice. The reason simply is that in case of question 1, you only know about the existence of $f''(a)$ and not $f''(a + h)$ or $f''(a - h)$. Same reasons apply to the second question.

Comment: @Priyatham: after your latest edit i have upvoted your answer. Good to know that you took effort to fix the mistake I point out. Thanks for the same.

Answer (score -3):

The first proof:
$$lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h)}{h^2}=$$using *De L'Hopital Rule*
$$=lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f'(a+h)+f'(a-h)}{2h}=\frac{f''(a+h)+f''(a-h)}{2}=\frac{f''(a)+f''(a)}{2}=f''(a)$$
Instead the second question:
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{4(f(h)-f(-h)-2(f(h/2)-f(-h/2)))}{h^3}=$$ applying *De L'Hopital Rule*
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{4(f'(h)+f'(-h)-f'(h/2)-f'(-h/2))}{3h^2} \\
= \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{4(f''(h)-f''(-h)-\frac{1}{2}f''(h/2)+\frac{1}{2}f''(-h/2))}{6h} \\
= \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{4(f'''(h)+f'''(-h)-\frac{1}{4}f'''(h/2)-\frac{1}{4}f'''(-h/2))}{6} \\
= \frac{6f'''(0)}{6} = f'''(0)$$

Comment: You must differentiate wrt h not a.